# Enable user interaction on a UIButton underneath a UIVew?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton, user-interaction

In my program I have configured a `UIView` to be placed over a number of `UIBUtton`s. This is so you can pan across the view and have the buttons move over as well as selecting the buttons themselves. However, it is not possible to select the buttons when they are underneath this `UIView`. Does anybody know how to configure a `UIButton`'s `userInteractionEnabled` while it is under these conditions?

Comment: Try to disable userInteraction on that UIView that covers the buttons.

Comment: I need the `userInteractionEnabled` for that view to be set to `true` so I can add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to it.

Comment: If this view is transparent and only serves for detecting pan-gesture then why not placing the buttons on top of the view?

Comment: I just tried that. The buttons block the `UIView` underneath from recognizing the pan events.

Comment: i see - so these buttons are probably close together? in that case you might want to consider using `UISCrollView` with buttons added to it's view.

Comment: Yes, they are. I haven't yet tried using a `UIScrollView` but I'm sure I can work it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique has worked for me - caveat: I just typed this in it's not compiled or nuthin it's given as a starting point.

1. Create the buttons and place them at the top of the view hierarchy (i.e. where they interact normally and respond to taps, on top of the UIView)
2. When creating the buttons - keep a reference to them in an array.

   NSMutableArray* arrayOfPeskyButtons;
3. Keep a record of the button frames

   ```
   NSMutableArray* arrayOfPeskyFrames = [NSMutableArray mutableArray];
   for ((UIButton*)button in arrayOfPeskyButtons)
   {
       [arrayOfPeskyFrames addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:button.frame];
   }
   ```
4. When your app responds to an action on the UIView - panning or if you change it to a UIScrollView (probably best btw), then move the frame of the buttons correspondingly so that they appear fixed in place to the user.

I have used this technique to create 'overlays' of buttons which sit on top of scrollviews and it works surprisingly well. Simply in the scrollView delegate method.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

take note of the scrollviews offset and adjust each of the frames of the buttons accordingly depending on the offset of the scrollView

```
 CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
```

Iterate through the array of buttons and move them.

```
 int index = 0;
 for ((UIButton*)button in arrayOfPeskyButtons)
 {
     CGRect originalFrame = [[arrayOfPeskyFrames objectAtIndex:index]CGRectValue];
     CGRect currentFrame = button.frame;
     //adjust frame
     //e.g.
     currentFrame.origin.x = originalFrame.origin.x + offset.x;

     button.frame = currentFrame.;
     index++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the value of the UIButton's userInteractionEnabled, you should set the userInteractionEnabled value of the UIView on top of the UIButton to no.

When the UIView's userInteractionEnabled is set to YES, the UIView was 'eating up' the events. The button would then never receive any events.

Comment: I understand that it's doing this. perhaps i was unclear in my question. It's important that the `UIView`'s `userInterActionEnabled` is set to `true` so it can recognize pan events.